# What is the difference between workspaces and projects

Tags: cloud9-ide

I have recently started using Cloud9 IDE (free) and it is great however I can only create 1 project on this package and I would like to upgrade to a paid version of the platform. But I do have a number of Projects mainly FTP project that I want to work on.

The question is what is the difference between workspaces and projects, can on a paid platform have unlimited projects?

Cloud9 IDE has a maximum of 16 Workspaces on it most expensive solution does that mean the projects are limited to 16 only?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Cloud9 workspaces == Cloud9 projects. The workspace limit is on non-free hosted workspaces i.e. any workspace that's private or larger than 1GB disk space and 512MB RAM (SSH workspaces are unlimited). More info at the [Cloud9 docs](https://docs.c9.io/v1.0/docs/picking-a-plan).

Answer (score 0):

You can just create new folders for new projects in a workspace. The downside is that you can't run (preview) them at the same time, and that they share hardware resources, but it's not that big of a deal. The projects are inside different folders just as on your computer, so Git, Bitbucket, automatic project generators and stuff like that will still consider the folder your project, not your "workspace".